# Trying to convert the inline queries in coldfusion to SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2014

I have the code as below in my coldfusion application. Now I would like to convert this inline queries into stored procedure. The issue that is causing from creating the stored procedure is due to the cfloop. How would I be able to do this in SQL stored procedure? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<cfquery name="qConflicts" datasource="#request.cpDSN#">
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  SELECT * INTO ##filteredTLI
  FROM (
    SELECT TLIReferenceNumber = NULL, Effective_Date = NULL, Expire_Date = NULL, Version = NULL
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(tliRecords)#" index="i">
      <cfset tliStruct = tliRecords[i] />
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT TliReferenceNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#tliStruct.tliReferenceNumber#" />, 
      Effective_Date=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#tliStruct.effective_date#" />, 
      Expire_Date = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#tliStruct.expire_date#" />,
      Version = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#tliStruct.version#" />
    </cfloop>
  )x
</cfquery>
```

Comment: How about we start with the table schemas and criteria that is being used to filter the data?

Comment: Back up a bit and look at how you created your array of structures.  It might be easier to put that part into a stored procedure than to pass it to a stored procedure.

Comment: @DanBracuk but how would I implement it? thanks

Comment: Not sure why the above needs a database query at all, let alone a stored proc. What else is being done with the data and why do you need to convert it to a procedure?

Comment: You are doing a select. Do not do a a stored procedure. Do a table valued function if anything. you need to come up with an approach to deal with the cfloop in the cfquery

Comment: Nothing *technically* wrong with using a stored proc, but ... unless there's more to it than what was shown, agreed it doesn't really provide much advantage over a query. That's why I am curious how the results are used AND what's the reasoning for converting it to a stored proc in the first place.